# Double description for images CCK field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've noticed the images in the products content type in ubercart shop have 2 description fields:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/doubleDescription.png

I was wondering if I can do this only with programming or there is some module to do it.

Also, it would be nice to have a text area instead of a single line text field for the description.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you describe is provided by [ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield), which is one of the modules recommended from Ubercart.

Comment: If I change the description field in ImageField to a text_area using hook_form_alter(), is it displayed as multi-line text in the front-end as well ?

Comment: Yes. If you change the form field to `#textarea`, the field will show as multi-line. `hook_form_alter()` doesn't have the concept of front-end, or back-end; it alters the form wherever it appears. Rather than implementing `hook_form_alter()`, I would suggest to implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, which allows to keep the code for altering a form separated from the code to alter another form.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not descriptions, those are image attributes that can be enabled during the content type definition.

I wouldn't recomment using long texts in ALT or TITLE, but if you really want to, you can change the field to a textarea implementing `hook_form_alter()` on that form.

Comment: If I change the description field in a CCK Field to text_area using hook_form_alter(), is it displayed as multi-line text in the front-end as well ?

Answer (score 1):

If you look under http://yoursite.com/admin/content/node-type/product/fields/field_image_cache you can see that under Title Text Settings and Alt Text Settings they have those enabled.  Just do the same on your content type with the Filefield -> Imagefield field type.

Comment: ok, I actually thought they were displayed beside the image, not as attributes.